# Problem modifying JSON config file inside a container (PHP)

Tags: php, json, docker

I have a problem modifying a JSON config file within a PHP7.4 container. Im supposed to be able to configure an HTTP GET request to make adjustments to this config file.

Ive ran the code on a PHP test server, with no issues, but cant seem to get the file permissions modified within the container.

Ive added the line `RUN mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-production" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"` inside the Dockerfile, taken from Docker hub PHP-apache documentation page. This stops previously encountered file permission problems, however, when i send the container the relevant request, it doesnt show any PHP errors, but the file also isnt being modified.

My Dockerfile;

```
FROM php:7.4-apache 
COPY src/ /var/www/html/

RUN mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-production" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"
```

Prior to building the container ive also ran `CHMOD 755 filename` on all files within my `/src` directory.

Ive tried modifying `chown` permissions as well, adding users (and running the container as an admin), but im getting Docker build errors when i try to add those features. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer;
I tried upgrading my chown permissions to 777... and its working... thanks for anyone who read or looked.

`chmod 777 filename|directory`